# ML.NET Detect anomalies with gaps/missings in data

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service, ml.net

I have done some tests with [DetectSpike](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.timeseriescatalog.detectiidspike?view=ml-dotnet) and [DetectAnomaly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.timeseriescatalog.detectanomalybysrcnn?view=ml-dotnet) but despite differences and whole pipeline building - both methods require input of 1-dimensional float[]

Its fine to find anomalies and spikes but I was asked to find anomalies "normal", and anomalies with gaps. (this can be one scenario no need to separate this by kind)

Example 1: WebService receives about 30-100 requests/min, then theres break/gap and no requests for few minutes.

Example 2: I am receiving one bill invoice with random value each month, and theres two months without invoices.
[image]
I guess, that I am not able to do this without Date/Time dimension/column.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using concatenate to add the Date/Time to the float[]?

Comment: @Nooby-Noob I am new to ML.NET but see no idea how I should parse datetime+int/float to float 1-dimension array (float[]). I guess it needs second datetime dimension something like custom object with LoadColumn attributes or atleast Dictionary<Datetime, float> or something like this.

Comment: Apologies, my comment was not thought through. I have described a way to include your Datetimes in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The time series as a 1 dimensional float[] should be a list of counts of events in sequential and equal units of time.

So for your example 1, you could choose minutes, then create a sequential List object of counts of webservice events occurring within each minute.

Maintain a separate List object of the corresponding Datetimes for each item in the count List.

The example in the [DetectEntireAnomonly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.timeseriescatalog.detectentireanomalybysrcnn?view=ml-dotnet) documentation shows how to predict a score for each index of your List of minutes, then you can find the corresponding index in your Datetime List to retrieve the Datetime of the anomaly.

Comment: Not sure its final solution. But I see a point now. For investigation perdiod grain create enumerable and put values where its possible and 0 where its not possible. But theres one problem with this.  0 vs NaN (null)

Comment: If your problem is with how to handle missing data, you might find  https://towardsdatascience.com/4-techniques-to-handle-missing-values-in-time-series-data-c3568589b5a8 useful.